# ERROR: Registering runner. forbidden (check registration token)

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to configure a new runner for GitLab CI and I keep getting the error

> ERROR: Registering runner... forbidden (check registration token) runner=4PzD2eFb
>   PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems

This is the command I run

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner register   
Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com/ci):
    https://gitlab.com/ci
    Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner:
    XXXXXXXXXXXX
    Please enter the gitlab-ci description for this runner:
    [gitlab-test]: runner
    Please enter the gitlab-ci tags for this runner (comma separated):
    docker
```

It also happens when I run the command

```
sudo gitlab-runner register
```

with the same parameters.

Any advice on how to solve this will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could arise from a multitude of reasons. Is your Gitlab instance running on Gitlab.com?

Could you post the last few lines of the logs which mention the above problem - can get these from the `admin panel -> logs -> production.log`.

A simple network test would be to try hitting the coordinator URL using `wgets` from the terminal you tried to install the runner. It might not have the localhost loopback configured properly.

If `wgets` doesn't return a 200 status code then add/check the localhost loopback:

In your `/etc/hosts` file should be

> 127.0.0.1 localhost

Other potential problems and/or solutions would depend on what your logs say...

Comment: Thanks for this! It was a problem with the hosts file!

Comment: I've just got the same error here. My problem was that my runner machine got blacklisted by [Rack Attack](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/rack_attack.html).